# How to display window.width in div on resize using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, expression

*UPDATE: I would really appreciate a more angular-ish solution ... ... although I have found a solution to my problem, I believe it is a lousy solution, because I basically just setup a window.resize listener  which then updates my div's innerhtml .... but I could have done that with plain js*

---

I would like to have a div that continually shows the innerWidth during resize.

I do not believe I need a directive on the div to do this. So currently I simply place an expression within the div, that I thought would update when $scope property of the same name updated:

```
  <body  ng-app        = "my_app"
         ng-controller = "my_controller">
    <div>{{the_width}}</div>
  </body>

  <script>
    var gvo_app  = angular.module( "my_app" , [] ) ;
    gvo_app
      .controller( "my_controller" ,
                   function( $window , $scope ) 
                      { angular
                          .element($window)
                            .on( 'resize' ,
                                  function( ) 
                                    { console.log('resize : ' + $window.innerWidth);
                                      $scope.the_width = $window.innerWidth ;
                                    }
                                )
                      }
                  )
  </script>
```

my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5JZwg4aUsRTvehqyzT44?p=preview)

Comment: The plunker seems to be working fine when I resize the html container, your solution seems to be fine :)

Comment: I just updated the plunker ... and added an answer that explains it ... thanks ..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed: `$scope.$digest();`

```
<script>
    var gvo_app  = angular.module( "my_app" , [] ) ;
    gvo_app
      .controller( "my_controller" ,
                   function( $window , $scope ) 
                      { angular
                          .element($window)
                            .on( 'resize' ,
                                  function( ) 
                                    { console.log('resize : ' + $window.innerWidth);
                                      $scope.the_width = $window.innerWidth ;
                                      $scope.$digest() ; // <<<<------
                                    }
                                )
                      }
                  )
  </script>
```

How did I make this mistake?

All introductory angularjs examples  that I have been working on over the last couple of days have shown most data-binding within `<input>` elements. And as it turns out `<input>` elements are a special case in angular, such that angular automatically creates a listener and calls it on state changes. I had thought that merely having the binding expression `{{my_variable}}` on any element, such as a `<div>`, would accomplish this ... but no.

I needed to force angular to call the listener, which is done in a round-about way using the angular 'service', `.$digest()` (which actually forces angular to look at every listener, and calls any and all that have changed since the previous `.digest()`).

This [article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html)  explains $watch and $digest ... 
*(angular does not seem to use the term 'listener', but instead 'watch', and 'digest' just flushes through all the 'watches' to see if they have been changed)*